# How would I read in a CSS file manually

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking to read CSS values that are not valid such as 'left: 50%-@@this.width;' But of course browsers strip invalid CSS out when they load so it would seem parsing the css before it's loaded would be the only way.

Right now the only solution I can see is to scan all the link and script tags then make an ajax request for the href of the links. This feels sloppy and I get the feeling there must be an easier way to do this. Any help on an easier way to get the raw css would be much appreciated.

I know of lesscss that does similar things to what I am trying to accomplish however I need a library-less solution.

Comment: you can use an ajax request to fetch the raw css from the server (assuming it's on the same server you're getting the JS code from). but do you really want to write your own css parser? You couldn't use this to validate arbitrary "other site" css because of cross-domain request restrictions, and why would you want to validate your own css? don't send bad css in the first place.

Comment: You'd only be able to get the file contents if the request was from the same domain. A simple AJAX call using an XHR would get you the file contents, jquery makes this easy as `$.get('/path/to/stylesheet.css').done(...)`

Comment: Marc: Reason for it is to write a library to extend css file functionality similar to the example given in the question; much like the library lesscss.